# Seekbar progress drawable abnormal behavior onPause

Tags: android, android-drawable, seekbar

I'm displaying a seekbar inside a fragment. The seekbar has custom thumb and progress drawables. They display fine, however when I pause the activity and return to it, the progress bar width strangely increases to the same height of the thumb ! I can't find the problem for this abnormal behavior.

how it displays normally
[image]

after activity pause
[image]

my code :

// inside fragment onStart

```
seekBar.setThumb(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.form_bg));
            seekBar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress));
```

// seekBar xml

```
<SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:indeterminate="false"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:max="100"
                    android:maxHeight="6dp"
                    android:progress="50" />
```

// thumb drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <size android:height="@dimen/seekbar_tumb_size" android:width="@dimen/seekbar_tumb_size" />
    <solid android:color="@color/form_color" />
</shape>
```

// progress drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:top="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:gravity="center_vertical"  android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>

        <solid android:color="@color/activity_bg" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:gravity="center_vertical" android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/form_color_syrup" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

Comment: What version are you running on? On earlier releases you had to use nine-patches; support for drawable XML resources was not at the level it is now.

Comment: I'm testing on Android 5.1 , however I used the same code in a previous app (used the seekbar inside an activity not fragment) and it worked correctly. I don't know what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution to this.

```
Rect bounds = seekBar.getProgressDrawable().getBounds();

    seekBar.setThumb(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.form_bg));
    seekBar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress));

seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setBounds(bounds);
```